# How to solve "Package org is not accessible" error in eclipse while importing org.junit.Assert.*?

Tags: eclipse

I am following a tutorial on unit testing from school and wrote JUnit tests for a method in a class. This is what the files look like : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9beV.png)

Why am I getting this error? All the annotations like @AfterClass are also underlined with error "cannot resolve @AfterClass to a type" How do I fix this ? I have programmed in Java for a year now but this is my first time using eclipse and writing JUnit test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done everything right up until this point and are still having issues with your junit imports, your **module-info.java** file is probably the culprit. If you don't need it, deleting it will silence the IDE complaints.

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit classes are in a library, which is not automatically made available to your project, unless you make it available.  For a simple exercise like this, you might have to download the JUnit jar file (https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install) , and create a "lib" directory in your project to store it.  Then, you add that jar to your project classpath.

Comment: thank you for the solution. I simply switched the project to a different IDE and it started working, but I will keep this in mind