# Don't we have a way to remove " org is not accessible " error in eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse

I'm trying to work with JSON file and in the middle of the code the notification "org is not accessible" shown up,

I tried a couple of ways shown in google but it is of no use.

Can anyone help me out to get by org accessible?

Comment: You need to tag your question correctly in order to attract the attention of somebody who could help.  Your previous tag, [tag:json.net] is for a JSON parsing library in c#/.NET which doesn't seem to apply here.  I changed the tags to [tag:json] and [tag:eclipse] but you should [edit] your question to add/correct any necessary tags.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging.  Also, try to give as much detail as possible about how to reproduce your problem, ideally a [mcve].  See [ask].

Comment: *I tried a couple of ways shown in google but it is of no use.* - then please [edit] your question to give ass much detail as possible about what you tried, you're more likely to get useful help if we already know what does not work. Possibly related: [Error: The package org.apache.commons is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056713/3744182), [The org. package in eclipse is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67002154/3744182), [How to solve "Package org is not accessible" error in eclipse while importing org.junit.Assert.*?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61629034/3744182).